# Add values to one string

Tags: cron, date

I would to like to copy one file on a certain day at 2:30 using crontab

Assume I have a file called 200516.txt I want to copy on May, 16th 2020

-> date +%y -- 20
-> date +%m -- 05
-> date +%d -- 16
-> fixed string ".txt"

30 2 * * * cp /test/STRING /output/

---> How do I build such a STRING?

Thanks!
Regards,
ET

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 1):

You can construct such a string directly with the `date` command ex.

```
$ date '+%y%m%d.txt' --date='May 16 2020'
200516.txt
```

However, `cron` is for commands that you want to run on a recurring schedule.

For scheduling a one-off command execution such as *"copy on May, 16th 2020"*, the appropriate command is `at`:

```
$ at 2:30 am 16 May 2020
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> cp /test/$(date '+%y%m%d.txt' --date='May 16 2020') /output
```

then hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

```
at> <EOT>
job 15 at Sat May 16 02:30:00 2020
```